# MonacaでCordova5.2にアップデート後、Androidのビルドができません。

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

MonacaでCordova4.1からCordova5.2にアップデートしたところ、Androidビルドに失敗します。
ビルド設定などの対応方法があれば、お教えください。

・ビルドではなくMonacaデバッガーで動作させた場合、特にエラーはなく動作します。
　・iOSビルドの場合、問題なくビルドに成功します。

ビルド失敗後のメッセージには、ビルド設定に間違いがある可能性があるので下記の設定を再確認してください
と表示されます。
　・AndroidManifest.xmlは正しく設定されていますか？
　・キーストアの設定が正しいですか？

以下はビルド失敗時のログになります。

```
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 5.2
plugin add mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pfctl: pf already enabled
Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add mobi.monaca.appccloud.appCCloudPlugin
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing "mobi.monaca.appccloud.appCCloudPlugin" for android
Fetching plugin "android.support.v4" via npm
WARNING: android.support.v4 has been renamed to cordova-plugin-android-support-v4. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you `cordova plugin rm android.support.v4` and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-support-v4`.
Fetching plugin "android.support.v4" via cordova plugins registry
Installing "android.support.v4" for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add plugin.push.nifty
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing "plugin.push.nifty" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'plugin.push.nifty':Error: Uh oh!
```

Comment: 現在組み込まれているプラグインを一度無効にし、再度有効にし直しても同様でしょうか？

Comment: @oTak 
oTak様
ご教示ありがとうございます。
一旦向こうにし、再度設定しましたがビルドできませんでした。